# Can you recommend any good walkthrough article on setting up a mail server on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I must set up a company mail server (smtp, imap, web mail, multiple domains, web-based administration) on an Ubuntu 10.04 Server this night. I've never done this before and have only the very-very basic idea on how does e-mail work. I was hoping to use iRedMail, but it does not work on 10.04. Can you point to a good easy HOWTO on setting up mail servers as they are meant to be today?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu help: [Setting up an Ubuntu System as an Email Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer)

> A Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) is the program which receives and sends out the email from your server, and is therefore the key part. The default MTA in Ubuntu is [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), but [exim4](http://www.exim.org/) is also fully supported and in the main repository

Some other references,

1. [Simple Mail Server Setup on Ubuntu](http://www.cowcomputing.com/2010/01/22/simple-mail-server-setup-on-ubuntu-step-by-step-guide/)
   <sup>Short Step By Step Guide</sup>
2. [How to set up a mail server on a GNU / Linux system](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/)
   Step by step guide to install Postfix
   <sup>Ubuntu + Postfix + Courier IMAP + MySQL + Amavisd-new + SpamAssassin + ClamAV + SASL + TLS + SquirrelMail/Roundcube + Postgrey</sup>

And, I hope you are using the **Lucid** [**Server Edition**](http://www.ubuntu.com/server).
A direct reference to Lucid (10.04) [**Email Services**](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/email-services.html) chapter of the [Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html).

Comment: Flurdy's doc is the best

Answer (score 1):

This should at least be a good start.  Exim4 is very easy to setup.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Exim4